# understanding a proof involving equivalence of norms in finite dim. linear normed spaces

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, banach-spaces

I am reading the proof of the theorem shown below (from Linear Functional Analysis by Rynne and Youngson). I can't figure out why the part I highlighted in red is true. I understand why $S$ is compact (it's the unit sphere), but I don't know why that implies that we can find a minimum amongst all $n$-tuples in $S$. Could someone explain that to me? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: $f(S)$ is a compact subset of $\Bbb R$, since $f$ is continuous. (Note $f$ should be defined to have range $\Bbb R$.)

Comment: @DavidMitra I still don't understand is why there exists a $(\mu_1, \ldots , \mu_n)\in S$ such that $f((\mu_1, \ldots , \mu_n))\leq f((\lambda_1, \ldots , \lambda_n))$ for all $(\lambda_1, \ldots , \lambda_n) \in S$.

Comment: continuous real valued functions assume its extreme values on compact sets

Answer (score 2):

Many have provided a good answer in the comments already, but I'll just spell out every detail here:

It is a standard fact (in topology) that the image of a compact set under a continuous map is compact, and in $\mathbb{R}^n$, compact is equivalent to closed and bounded.  So, for the continuous map $f:S\to \mathbb{R}$, $f(S)$ is a closed and bounded set in $\mathbb{R}$.  Since it is bounded, infimum (greatest lower bound) of $f(S)$ exists, which we'll call $m$. And $f(S)$ closed tells us that $m\in f(S)$, so there exists $\vec\mu$ such that $m=f(\vec\mu)$